# Wordpress dynamic subpage for ACF

Tags: urls, advanced-custom-fields, routing

I'm using ACF to add additional data to my post types.

Concretely, I'm using repeater field to add new item with a title and content box.

My article has url like this :

```
mydomain.com/2016/10/24/article-title/
```

I would like to allow my page viewers to see details of my repeater fields that are related to this specific article on a separate url like this one :

```
mydomain.com/2016/10/24/article-title/repeater-field-title
```

where I would show only title and content from repeater field where `repeater-field-title` part of `url` matches title of a certain repeated field related to my article.

How can I achieve this with wordpress?

Comment: How exactly is that information stored?

Comment: as a set of repeated fields within a post

Comment: I don't believe that. This is more likely in a post_meta or some other place. The posts table doesn't have a column for that.

Comment: As I said, I'm using ACF with repeater field which is meta field. But it is completely irrelevant. I'm more interested at how I can capture this extra url argument and than in my template decide what fields to show depending on the value.

Comment: This **is** relevant when you want to build your permalinks based on it.